# I wanted to understand how the windows(new rectangle(30, 20)) is working in following code

Tags: c++, object-composition

So i know that `new` and `delete` implicitly call constructor but i couldn't get my head around how `window(new rectangle (30, 20))` is working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

class Rectangle
{    
     private:
         double height, width;
     public:
         Rectangle(double h, double w) {
             height = h;
             width = w;
         }
         double area() {
         cout << "Area of Rect. Window = ";
         return height*width;
         }
};

class Window 
{
    public: 
        Window(Rectangle *r) : rectangle(r){}
        double area() {
            return rectangle->area();
        }
    private:
        Rectangle *rectangle;
};


int main() 
{
    Window *wRect = new Window(new Rectangle(10,20));
    cout << wRect->area();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you don't know.

Comment: Please read how to ask(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and proof before posting. Your heading does not match your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Window`'s constructor takes one parameter, a pointer to a `Rectangle`.

```
new Rectangle(10,20)
```

This expression constructs a `new` instance of the `Rectangle` class, giving you a pointer to the `new` class instance.

So:

```
Window *wRect = new Window(new Rectangle(10,20));
```

After obtaining a pointer to the new instance of the `Rectangle` class, the pointer gets passed to `Window`'s constructor, for a `new` instance of the `Window` class.